# Manually generate a timer interrupt

Tags: linux, timer, interrupt

On my machine;

**/proc/interrupts**

```
          CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
  0:         54          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:         10          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  6:          2          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      floppy
  8:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:         16          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 14:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
 15:    3984107          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
 16:          2          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   vmwgfx
 17:     980727     939643    1334876     770403   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ioc0
 24:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
 25:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
 26:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
 27:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
 28:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      PCIe PME, pciehp
```

I understand interrupts, I want to learn about timer interrupts.
[This page](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596000022/0596000022_ch05-5-fm2xml.html) says that, Each occurrence of a timer interrupt triggers the following major activities like Updates the time elapsed since system startup.

on my machine it says 54 only but the machine is up from days.

What am I missing here?

Second question is, How can I manually generate an interrupt so that the count becomes 55 from 54?

Comment: Why do you ask? What piece of software is interested in that interrupt?

Comment: Just curious If I can generate an interrupt on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't generate timer [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt). The hardware does (perhaps hundreds interrupts per second). And the kernel configures the hardware to do that.

Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), which is the way to deal with time related stuff from user-land Linux application programs (which probably should matter to you more).

If you cared about handling interrupts, you would write your own OS [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) and [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) (and then the `linux` tag would be off-topic). See [*Operating systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable). For practical hints on OS development, see [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/) wiki.

The operating system is here to hide you hardware details like interrupts and to manage hardware and provide you abstractions above it. `/proc/interrupts` is simply a way to *query* the OS kernel state. Its format varies with kernel versions and hardware (on my system the output is quite different from yours), and it mostly is useful for sysadmins (e.g. as hint for hardware malfunction, when some weird piece of hardware sends a lot of interrupts). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

> How can I manually generate an interrupt

Within a Linux system, **you cannot.**

BTW, Linux also has [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)-s (see also [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)...) but these signals are not interrupts (even if *some* interrupts might indirectly trigger signals). And [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) can indeed "interrupt" (in a very figurative way, not the same as hardware interrupts) your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

<sup>(it could be possible that on your particular hardware and kernel, most "timer" interrupts go into the `ioc0` line)</sup>

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What about the CPU0 having 54 timer interrupts?

Comment: I have no idea, but the kernel does.